# create hotkey for linux passwords

Tags: linux, shell, passwords

In linux, Is there a way I can save my long/complex passwords I have to type like hundreds times daily basis somewhere and create a hot key against them so that every time i want to input the password, I can just use the hot key?

Comment: SSH passwords? If yes, use keyfiles instead of passwords.

Comment: No, I know ssh key stuff. But this is more like a bunch of test server s get wiped out everyday. Setting up the key files is not really a good choice here.

Comment: IMO, this belongs to SuperUser.

Comment: You should configure whatever tool is setting up the test server to add your keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some sort of password manager like kwallet, i personally use keepass on windows. Pressing ctrl+alt+a autotypes passwords.